# How to INSERT Records in SQL Database and show the Number of Records Entered?

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert-into

Using VB .NET I am trying to `INSERT INTO` an SQL DataTable 27019 Records. The `INSERT INTO` process goes well on clicking the 'Insert Button' but is time consuming. Therefore, I want to be able to see as and when the records are being entered by showing in Label/TextBox their progress. For example when the first record is inserted the text should be *"1/27019 record(s) Entered"*, for the next records it should be *"2/27019 record(s) Entered"* and so on.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where from data comes? I'd suggest to use `SQLBulkCopy` class instead `INSERT INTO ..` execued in a loop.

Comment: @Maciej Los the issue is not with the Insert command functionality. It is working fine. I want to show in a label or textbox progressively how many records have been entered so far...as 1/27019 record(s) entered...and so on.

Comment: When such of portion of data is inserted into database, it might cause database crash. So, my suggestion is still alive ;)

Comment: Updating the GUI (label or textbox) while you're running a "loop" process is a little tricky, [see this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/729674/Simple-Net-progress-bar-using-async-await) for information on one way to do it.

Comment: BTW, you can catch rows inserted via SqlRowsCopied event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I believe SqlRowsCopied is only fired when using SqlBulkcopy and only if you select a batch size smaller than the number of inserted rows.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but they are likely to increase the total load time. You could either split up the insert into multiple batches and fire an event after each completed batch, but this will obviously take longer. Alternatively if there is no other process writing to this table at the same time you could fire off a separate thread before you start the insert, that queries how many records are inserted. You can either use with(nolock) for this query or set the transaction level to read uncommitted. It is not guaranteed that these dirty reads will always return the correct amount of rows, however, for a progress bar is its probably accurate enough.